# Shift-Arrow keys working in KiTTY but not PuTTY for nested tmux configuration

Tags: putty, tmux, kitty

For years I have been using a different prefix key for nested instances on tmux.  I use `\` on my own server, but `a` for any other servers I connect to and start a nested tmux session.

**[I have found this trick](http://stahlke.org/dan/tmux-nested/)** which uses <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Keys</kbd> to switch between windows and nested instances, which is much better.

However, it does not work when I am using PuTTY (using Windows) but it does when I use [KiTTY](http://kitty.9bis.net/).  I cannot figure out why it is not working with PuTTY.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>Arrow Keys</kbd> returns the same codes in the terminal when using either programs.

---

**EDIT:**

Just after starting a bounty I have realized that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Keys</kbd> does actually come up with different codes.

**PuTTY:**

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> = `^[OD`

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> = `^[OC`

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> = `^[OA`

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> = `^[OB`

**KiTTY:**

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> = `^[[1;2D`

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> = `^[[1;2C`

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> = `^[[1;2A`

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> = `^[[1;2B`

So how do I change PuTTY so that it sends the same codes with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow Keys</kbd>?

Comment: Just after I started the bounty I realised that shift+arrow keys does come up with different escape codes for the programs, so I will accept an answer on how to change the codes in putty to the ones that work, as I cannot cancel the bounty.

Comment: Have you tried to change PuTTY configuration: Terminal, Keyboard section?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I am looking at the options there but cannot see anything relevant.  I have updated my question. If you can figure it out I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is you can't, since this is a bug in PuTTY. This was discussed some time ago at stack - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6202310/putty-shift-arrows

I had the similar problem with tmux and PuTTY, and I switched to KiTTY.

Answer (score 1):

I also cannot manage to find any method for remapping keys in PuTTY,
so I suggest using a [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) script.

An example script that maps <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Right</kbd> to the keys
<kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>;</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>,
but only for windows whose title contains `putty.exe`, is:

```
#IfWinActive, putty.exe
+Right::SendInput, {esc}[1;2D
#IfWinActive
```

Place the script in a file with the suffix `.ahk` and double-click to test.
If it works, you could copy it to the Startup scripts folder so it starts
when you logon.

Answer (score 0):

Since Kitty is a fork of Putty they have very similar settings. Mostly likely your `Terminal > Keyboard` settings are different between Kitty and Putty. Making the Putty settings match the Kitty settings (as close as possible) should resolve the problem for you. Particularly `The Function keys and keypad`. Also, check the `Terminal > Features` section as well.